# Difference between lc and c / ls and s in printf

Tags: c, printf, stdio

What's the difference between lc (C) and c / ls (S) and s in `printf()` function? Why does ls (S) conversion return -1?

Exemple :

```
printf("%C", 'ͳʹ); // -1
printf("%c", 'ͳʹ); // PRINT
printf("%S", "ͳ ans T"); // -1
printf("%s", "ͳ and T"); // PRINT
```

On mac..

Comment: can you phrase your question more clearly - not sure what (C) and (S) are supposed to represent

Comment: C for lc, but it's obsolet like S for ls

Comment: Downvoted, because question doesn't show any code that would return such value. Please read on [mcve].

Comment: also include which compiler and library you are using and what compilation switches; before C99 there were various incompatible implementations of wide string printing; and after C99 at least one major compiler stuck with what they had instead of switching to the standard, or offered standard as a switch

Comment: Add sample code to illustrate what you mean. I think you are talking about format specifiers, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @potheo Do you have a cite about the obsoluteness of `S`?

Comment: Note that **conversion specifier** `%S` is not standardized (!) so you won't find it in the newer *ISO C draft* (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf) and consequently neither on a well known page like *Creference* (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). So my advice to all is to use standardized way which is using a **conversion specifier** `%s` prefixed with a **length modifier** `l` and you get `%ls` which does exactly the same as `%S` that I can't find documented nowhere (!).

Answer (score 5):

From the manual page:

> `l`
>
> (ell) [...] or a following `c` conversion corresponds to a `wint_t` argument, or a following `s` conversion corresponds to a pointer to `wchar_t` argument.

So the change is in which type is expected:

- `%c`- `int` which is internally converted to `unsigned char`
- `%lc` - `wint_t`
- `%s` - pointer to zero-terminated array of `char`
- `%ls` - pointer to zero-terminated array of `wchar_t`

A negative return value, such as `-1`, from `printf()` indicates that an error occured. It's hard to pinpoint further since you're not showing *any* code.